# clipPath transform on :focus/:hover for multiple instances of same icon

Tags: css, svg, mask, css-transforms, clip-path

I have an SVG icon with some masked shapes comprised of:

- `book-1`: masked by clipPath `mask-1`
- `book-2`: masked by clipPath `mask-2`
- `book-3`: not masked, no transform required

On `:focus` / `:hover` I want `mask-1` (but not `book-1`), and `book-2` (but not `mask-2`) to transform. Straightforward enough…

```
<a href="whatevs" class="icon">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 44">
        <defs>
            <style>
                #book-1 {clip-path:url(#mask-1);} 
                #book-2 {clip-path:url(#mask-2);}
            </style>

            <clipPath id="mask-1">
                <path class="nudge" fill="none" … />
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="mask-2">
                <path fill="none" … />
            </clipPath>
        </defs>

        <g id="book-1">
            <path fill="#fff" … />
        </g>
        <g id="book-2">
            <path fill="#fff" class="nudge" … />
        </g>
        <path fill="#fff" … /> <!-- book-3 -->
    </svg>
</a>

/* CSS */

.icon .nudge {
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}

.icon:focus .nudge, 
.icon:hover .nudge {
    transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
}
```

But the fun begins when there are multiple instances of the same icon in a page.

---

I have 3 Pens on CodePen, each with 2 instances of the linked icon, where:

1. [MRYwBq](https://codepen.io/urlyman/pen/MRYwBq) **fails** with:

   - verbose code stating the full SVG each time it appears
   - class names for `book-1` and `book-2`
   - unique id names for every instance of just the masks: `mask-1` and `mask-2`
2. [qwEZrG](https://codepen.io/urlyman/pen/qwEZrG) **works** with:

   - verbose code stating the full SVG each time it appears
   - unique id names for every instance of the books and the masks: `book-1`, `mask-1`, `book-2` and `mask-2`
3. [gybrvL](https://codepen.io/urlyman/pen/gybrvL) **fails** with:

   - a `<symbol>` instance of the icon iterated via `<use>` in the page

### Thoughts

1. This is just weird. I’d like to understand why it fails the way it does.
2. It’s good that this works but I would prefer not to have to iterate the IDs with JavaScript after they have been sent to the page undifferentiated.
3. This is what I’d like to get working, but I don’t know if that’s possible.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `clip-path` requires an id of a svg `def` child, only one of these `<clipPath>` definitions will be taken into account in case multiple icons are placed on a page. That's why transforming the `<clipPath>` elements is a no-go, as all items referencing it will be affected. As a consequence, we need a solution that does not move or modify these elements based on `:hover` of `:focus`.

Fortunately, it is possible to move just the clipping path assigned to an element "without" moving the element itself by using the following trick:

1. Assign the clip path to the parent
2. Move the parent in the direction that the clip path should move
3. Move all children in the opposite direction

An example of this trick based on the code you provided can be found in the snippet below:

```css
a .nudge, a .unnudge {
  transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
}

a:focus, 
a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
    
a:focus .nudge, 
a:hover .nudge {
    transform: translate(-2px, 2px);
}

a:focus .unnudge, 
a:hover .unnudge {
    transform: translate(2px, -2px);
}


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  max-width: 36em;
  color: #333;
}

code {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<p>Instance 1: 
  <a href="#">
    <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 44" width="44" height="44">
      <defs>
          <style>
              .book-1{clip-path:url(#mask-1-1);}
              .book-2{clip-path:url(#mask-2-1);}
          </style>
          <clipPath id="mask-1-1">
              <path fill="none" d="M13.823,33.1V18.293a4.738,4.738,0,0,1,1.4-3.371S24.6,5.531,25.085,5.048L20.019-.019H8.143V33.1Z"/>
          </clipPath>
          <clipPath id="mask-2-1">
              <path fill="none" d="M31.814,10.117,21.12,20.822a4.733,4.733,0,0,0-1.4,3.371V39H12V7H28.7Z"/>
          </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g class="nudge book-1" >
          <path fill="#fff" class="unnudge" d="M22.736,5.72a1.193,1.193,0,0,0-1.686,0l-7.516,7.516a1.191,1.191,0,0,1-1.685-1.685l7.516-7.516a1.192,1.192,0,0,0-1.686-1.686L10.163,9.865h0a3.565,3.565,0,0,0-1.047,2.529h0V26.625h0a3.576,3.576,0,0,0,6.1,2.528h0l7.516-7.516a1.188,1.188,0,0,0,.349-.843V6.563A1.188,1.188,0,0,0,22.736,5.72Z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="book-2">
          <path fill="#fff" class="nudge" d="M21.723,22.193a4.733,4.733,0,0,1,1.4-3.371l5.865-5.871v-.488a1.192,1.192,0,0,0-2.035-.843l-7.516,7.516a1.192,1.192,0,0,1-1.686-1.686l7.516-7.516a1.191,1.191,0,1,0-1.685-1.685l-7.516,7.516a3.561,3.561,0,0,0-1.048,2.528h0V32.524h0a3.577,3.577,0,0,0,6.105,2.529h0l.6-.6Z"/>
      </g>
      <path fill="#fff" d="M34.535,17.52a1.19,1.19,0,0,0-1.685,0l-7.516,7.516a1.192,1.192,0,0,1-1.686-1.686l7.516-7.516a1.192,1.192,0,1,0-1.686-1.685l-7.516,7.516h0a3.564,3.564,0,0,0-1.047,2.528h0V38.424h0a3.576,3.576,0,0,0,6.1,2.529h0l7.516-7.516a1.188,1.188,0,0,0,.349-.843V18.363A1.188,1.188,0,0,0,34.535,17.52Z"/>
  </svg>
  </a>
</p>
<p>Instance 2, exact copy of instance 1: 
  <a href="#">
    <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 44" width="44" height="44">
      <defs>
          <style>
              .book-1{clip-path:url(#mask-1-1);}
              .book-2{clip-path:url(#mask-2-1);}
          </style>
          <clipPath id="mask-1-1">
              <path fill="none" d="M13.823,33.1V18.293a4.738,4.738,0,0,1,1.4-3.371S24.6,5.531,25.085,5.048L20.019-.019H8.143V33.1Z"/>
          </clipPath>
          <clipPath id="mask-2-1">
              <path fill="none" d="M31.814,10.117,21.12,20.822a4.733,4.733,0,0,0-1.4,3.371V39H12V7H28.7Z"/>
          </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <g class="nudge book-1" >
          <path fill="#fff" class="unnudge" d="M22.736,5.72a1.193,1.193,0,0,0-1.686,0l-7.516,7.516a1.191,1.191,0,0,1-1.685-1.685l7.516-7.516a1.192,1.192,0,0,0-1.686-1.686L10.163,9.865h0a3.565,3.565,0,0,0-1.047,2.529h0V26.625h0a3.576,3.576,0,0,0,6.1,2.528h0l7.516-7.516a1.188,1.188,0,0,0,.349-.843V6.563A1.188,1.188,0,0,0,22.736,5.72Z"/>
      </g>
      <g class="book-2">
          <path fill="#fff" class="nudge" d="M21.723,22.193a4.733,4.733,0,0,1,1.4-3.371l5.865-5.871v-.488a1.192,1.192,0,0,0-2.035-.843l-7.516,7.516a1.192,1.192,0,0,1-1.686-1.686l7.516-7.516a1.191,1.191,0,1,0-1.685-1.685l-7.516,7.516a3.561,3.561,0,0,0-1.048,2.528h0V32.524h0a3.577,3.577,0,0,0,6.105,2.529h0l.6-.6Z"/>
      </g>
      <path fill="#fff" d="M34.535,17.52a1.19,1.19,0,0,0-1.685,0l-7.516,7.516a1.192,1.192,0,0,1-1.686-1.686l7.516-7.516a1.192,1.192,0,1,0-1.686-1.685l-7.516,7.516h0a3.564,3.564,0,0,0-1.047,2.528h0V38.424h0a3.576,3.576,0,0,0,6.1,2.529h0l7.516-7.516a1.188,1.188,0,0,0,.349-.843V18.363A1.188,1.188,0,0,0,34.535,17.52Z"/>
  </svg>
  </a>
</p>
```

Please note, that this solution is not perfect, and the trick with having two opposite movements that should sum up to no movement, can result in a bit of jerkiness of the `.book-1` on some browsers (e.g. Firefox).

Comment: Thanks very much Piotr. Good insights.